# Are redundant columns in SQL beneficial if I'm expecting more reads than writes?

Tags: sql, database, performance, scalability, database-performance

Suppose I have a database that contains numerical ratings for a shop, and my app needs to be able to read the average ratings of a shop:

**Shop table:** *id (pk), name (varchar), average_rating (float - redundant column)*

**Rating table:**
*id (pk), rating_num (int), shop_id (int)*

It would obviously be best practice to simply recalculate the average rating from the rating table for consistency; however, it is expected from the previous version of this app that about **80% of the queries will be reads to know the average rating of a shop**. In other words, writing ratings will be much rarer than reading the average ratings of a shop.

If I were to structure my database in this manner, I wouldn't need an extra join or query to hop on over to the rating table. Is there any caveat to this?

Comment: Depending on what database you are using you could possibly use a [materialized or indexed view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) to accomplish the same thing. I would explore that path if your server supports it (Oracle, MSSQL, and Postgresql does, among others).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, what about databases that don't support materialized views?

Comment: I think your approach is fine; I guess you would have to update the cached average using a trigger or scheduled job depending on how up to date you want it, but I don't see any big issues with it.

Comment: There is a time and a place for everything.  I help maintain a data warehouse which contains, among other things, summary tables.  These tables are for reporting only, and contain calculated values.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to address this scenario in Sql Server is with an [*Indexed View*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html), and MySql call them *Materialized Views*.

An indexed view can handle keeping the average rating data up to date for you automatically, without needing to actually duplicate it in the table. Or course, the data is still duplicated in the view. The difference is that you only need to tell Sql Server what that data looks like. You don't need to manage keeping it current yourself.

Comment: The disadvantage is that it is slower (or can be, unless you're REALLY REALLY CAREFUL and know exactly what you're doing.) Given that performance is the source of this question, I assume that performance optimization is the main goal.

Comment: It's only slower if you have a _lot_ of writes, and having more reads was an explicit part of the question. Anyway, the performance part of the problem smacks of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that that's totally fine and likely will save some read traffic, especially if you need to look up the shop name anyway.

You'd probably update the average rating within a transaction where you insert a new rating. An alternative is to create a trigger to do it. Which you prefer is more a matter of taste, as the work done will be approximately the same.

Then you'll want a key on `(shop_id, rating_num)`, to make calculating the new average rating of a shop efficient (assuming `rating_num` is the actual rating score.)

Comment: Sorry, but can you please explain why an index is needed for rating_num?

Comment: I'm assuming "rating_num" is the actual rating given (1 .. 5 or whatever) because I see no other column that could be that.

The index I suggest is known as a "covering index" -- if you only have index on "shop_id" in the ratings table, then the database engine has to go to the row itself after it finds the shop in the index, which will be very scattered I/O and terrible performance to calculate the average rating_num.  With all the data you need in the index, I/O will be contiguous, and it won't even need to go to the base table storage.